# IE Print removes paragraph from the bottom

Tags: css, printing

Having a problem with printing page in IE.

i have two paragraphs.

```
 <p style="width: 25.5pt; text-align: right; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px;"> [1] </p>
 <p  style="height: 1%; text-indent: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: -12pt; position: relative; top: -12pt;"> This is the text that i do not see </p>
```

On my website this is how it looks

[1]   This is the text that i do not see

When i print this is the last paragraph at the bottom of the page  and only the first paragraph is shown and the second paragraph does not show on the next page either.

Sorry if i am not very clear. Please help.

Comment: Which version of IE?  Also, could you clean up your sample code so that it is identical to the markup you are using?

Comment: on a sidenote, 0 does not need a unit, 0L water === 0 monkeys

Comment: @mark yeah debugging someone else's css

Answer (score 1):

you specify:

```
<p style="...position: relative; top: -12pt;">This is the text that i do not see </p>
```

So basically, the paragraph is on your printed page -12pt (16px) above it.

You need to define a relative parent element, from where the paragraph will be positioned `top: -12pt;` at.